# SQL query to return rows, starting with the latest, whose values sum to value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `Table1` has historical transactions and `Table2` has a field that stores the balance of those transactions for each account.

I need a `SQL query` that will return the transactions in `Table1` for a specific account, starting from the latest transaction that sum up to the current balance in `Table2`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table1**

> UniqID .  AcctNum  . TranType . TranDate . TranAmt
>  
>   1 . . . . . 1001123 . . . . A . . . . . 11/1/13 . . . . 100
>  
>   2 . . . . . 1010877 . . . . B . . . . . 12/2/13 . . . . . 10
>  
>   7 . . . . . 1010877 . . . . C . . . . . 12/2/13 . . . . . 22
>  
>   10. . . .. 1001123 . . . . A . . . . . 12/2/14 . . . .-100
>  
>   11. . . .. 1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 12/6/13 . . . . 145
>  
>   12. . . .. 1003699 . . . . A . . . . . 12/8/13 . . . . 250
>  
>   13. . . .. 1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/2/14 . . . . . 145
>  
>   14. . . .    .1003699    . . . . C . . . . . 1/4/14 . . . . . 110
>  
>   15. . . .    .1003699 . . . . C . . . . . 1/4/14 . . . . .-110
>  
>   19. . . .    .1003699 . . . . B . . . . . 1/8/14 . . . . . . 25
>  
>   21. . . .    .1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/2/14 . . . . . . 80
>  
>   22. . . .    .1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/8/14 . . . . . . 45
>  
>   26. . . .    .1001123 . . . . A . . . . . 1/21/14 . . . .-145

**Table2**

> AcctNum . TranBal
>   1001123 . . . . 270
>   1003699 . . . . 275
>   1010877 . . . . . 32

Expected Result for account 1001123

> UniqID .  AcctNum  . TranType . TranDate . TranAmt
>  
>   11. . . .. 1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 12/6/13 . . . . 145
>  
>   13. . . .. 1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/2/14 . . . . . 145
>  
>   21. . . .    .1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/2/14 . . . . . . 80
>  
>   22. . . .    .1001123 . . . . B . . . . . 1/8/14 . . . . . . 45
>  
>   26. . . .    .1001123 . . . . A . . . . . 1/21/14 . . . .-145

Comment: OK. What have you already tried?

Comment: logic behind not taking UniqID 1 and 10?

Comment: Technically UniqID 1 and 10 would result in 0, and by your "add up to" logic, should be included as well. However, what if they weren't a 0 result? would you want them included if one was over or under by an arbitrary amount?

Comment: Not sure what OP is getting at exactly, but here's a SQL Fiddle to play around with when he clarifies: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e85fc0/4

Comment: I only want to pull the transactions that make up the existing balnace.  Some of the records could contain years worth of transactions that are irrevelant if they sum to zero.

Comment: @VBlades I copied the query into SQL Server 2008 and I'm gettign a syntax error on the : where ever Balance := appears. Is this due to the version I'm using?

Comment: Well, because it's MySQL code.  You didn't tag this sql-server, you listed it as mysql.  The implementation will have to be a bit different...have to think about it.  Thanks for clarifying, but it seems a bit strange and arbitrary not to care about all the transactions which play into the total balance.

Comment: @VBlades Sorry about the errant tag. I gotten to the point where I get a running total for each transaction but can't figure out how to limit the result to the transactions that compromise the total from Table2. The purpose of the query is to produce a report that breaks down the total for each account into the detailed transactions

Comment: All_Is_Good, ALL the transactions for each AccNum are taken into account by your balance table, so I'm not sure what you are trying to figure out.

Comment: @VBlades  Each account could have hundreds on transactions, most of which are no longer relevant as they were assessed and then paid so they are no due. I need to return only the rows that make up the total amount from the other table.

Comment: I don't get the logic here. Consider UniqIDs 1,10 and 11. The TranDate of 11 is between the TranDate of 1 and 10, so the the sequence based on the TranDate (and i don't see another attribute which would make sense) is 1 - 11 - 10. So why do 1 and 10 nullify each other?

Comment: I apologize, the date for UniqID 10 should be 2013 not 2014.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think i got it now. First you will need a running total of TranAmt per AcctNum. In SQL Server 2012 this can be conveniently done by OVER PARTITION:

```
SELECT t.AcctNum, t.TranAmt,t.TranDate, SUM(t.TranAmt) OVER(PARTITION BY t.AcctNum ORDER BY t.TranDate,t.UniqID)
FROM Transactions t
```

I used UniqID because TranDate is not unique per AcctNum. In SQL Server 2008 you can't use OVER PARTITION because the ORDER BY clause was only added in SQL Server 2012 so we must use a JOIN here:

```
SELECT t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate, t1.TranAmt, SUM(t2.TranAmt) running_total
FROM   Transactions t1,
        Transactions t2
WHERE t1.TranDate >= t2.TranDate AND t1.AcctNum=t2.AcctNum AND t1.UniqID>=t2.UniqID
GROUP BY t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate, t1.TranAmt
ORDER BY t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate
```

Now we need only the rows where the running_total is 0 because they give us the threshold date before which the transaction data can be discarded:

```
    SELECT t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate, t1.TranAmt, SUM(t2.TranAmt) running_total
    FROM   Transactions t1,
            Transactions t2
    WHERE t1.TranDate >= t2.TranDate AND t1.AcctNum=t2.AcctNum AND t1.UniqID>=t2.UniqID
    GROUP BY t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate, t1.TranAmt
    HAVING SUM(t2.TranAmt)=0
    ORDER BY t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate
```

Finally we have to link those Threshold dates to the Transaction table again. I use a left join and to add the row with the threshold date to any row in Transaction which is equal or before that date (per AcctNum). Then we can discard those and keep only the rows which have date newer than threshold date.

```
SELECT *
FROM Transactions t
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate ThresholdDate, t1.TranAmt, SUM(t2.TranAmt) running_total
                FROM   Transactions t1,
                        Transactions t2
                WHERE t1.TranDate >= t2.TranDate AND t1.AcctNum=t2.AcctNum AND t1.UniqID>=t2.UniqID
                GROUP BY t1.AcctNum, t1.TranDate, t1.TranAmt
                HAVING SUM(t2.TranAmt)=0) td ON t.AcctNum=td.AcctNum AND t.TranDate<=td.ThresholdDate
WHERE td.AcctNum is null
ORDER BY t.AcctNum, t.TranDate
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could not get the query to finish. Is ThresholdDate supposed to be a separate column? I don't see where this is created in the sub-query. The query was also supposed to return records for one account, in this example 1001123

Comment: I played around with the queries and everything was fine in my testbed. What error do you get? ThresholdDate is calculated in the Subquery. It is the date, where the running total is zero which means everything before this date can be discarded. Reducing the thing to one account is only a small change in the Where clause...